# Cycle through python variable

Tags: python

I have a variable that can look something like this:

```
('[{"path": ["$.parent_field.field_1"], "category": "A"}, {"path": ["$.field_2"], "category": "B"}, {"path": ["$.null_path"], "category": "C"}]',)
```

Essentially I'm looking for the best way to 'cycle through' the variable

What I want to end up with is something like:

```
parent_field.field_1 and field_2
```

So I'm essentially looking to extract the path fields (after the `$.`) unless it is `null_path`

I've tried (where p is equal to the variable):

```
for i in p:
   print(i)
```

but that is giving me i as:

```
[{"path": ["$.parent_field.field_1"], "category": "A"}, {"path": ["$.field_2"], "category": "B"}, {"path": ["$.null_path"], "category": "C"}]
```

And then I am unable to cycle through i as hoped

Comment: Is that really what your variable looks like? It is a *string representation* of a *python tuple* of a *python list* of *python dict*s which seems weird. How did you get it?

Comment: I'm using psycopg2 and it is returned from a select statement on the DB, so psycopg2 puts the outer bracket on it I think

Comment: It's not the outer brackets that are the real problem, it's the outer quotes. What you want is the actual list of dicts: `[{...}, {...}]`, not its string version. You can get that via `eval` but I suspect there's a more direct way. (I don't know anything about psycopg2.)

Comment: The string value is valid json. So just do `json.loads(i)`.

Comment: Ah, so it's `json` not a `dict`. That makes sense. Thx, @ekhumoro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to do it in a while loop and replacing the old string at each iteration:

```
s = '[{"path": ["$.parent_field.field_1"], "category": "A"}, {"path": ["$.field_2"], "category": "B"}, {"path": ["$.null_path"], "category": "C"}]'

while True:
    start = s.find('["$.')+4
    end = s.find('"]')
    if start>0 and end>0:
        print(s[start:end])
        s = s[end+1:]
    else:
        break
```

Giving you the following print out:

```
parent_field.field_1
field_2
null_path
```

----- Edit ------

A better way might be to do it like this, if the variable `s` is structured as follows:

```
s = ('[{"path": ["$.parent_field.field_1"], "category": "A"}', '{"path": ["$.field_2"], "category": "B"}', '{"path": ["$.null_path"], "category": "C"}]')

for sub_s in s:
    start = sub_s.find('["$.')+4
    end = sub_s.find('"]')
    if start>0 and end>0:
        print(sub_s[start:end])
```

Giving the exact same printout

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to convert the `json` string to a `dict`, and then find the appropriate entries:

```
import json
result = json.loads(p[0])  ### it's a single-element tuple
paths = []
for pathdict in result:
    paths.append(pathdict['path'][0]) ## single-element lists

print(path)
```

which gives

```
['$.parent_field.field_1', '$.field_2', '$.null_path']
```

If you actually want more than just the `'path'` element, you can loop over the `pathdict`s in various ways.

Comment: The string is actually a list of dicts

Comment: Heh. But it is enough like json that your `json.loads` suggestion still works...

Comment: Well, it **is** json. The top level item can be a list or a dict, and can also contain any combination of similar objects. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#Data_types_and_syntax).